# PHP - What is the best practice for getting the ftp list from the remote server?

Tags: php, ftp

What is the best practice for getting the ftp file list from the remote server?

1) Using ftp_connect() function

```
<?php

// set up connection
$conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login = ftp_login($conn, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// get contents of the current directory
$content = ftp_nlist($conn, ".");

// output content
var_dump($content);
?>
```

or

2) Using scandir() and then output the file list with print_r()

```
<?php

$path = "ftp://login:password@ftpserver";

$files = scandir($path);

print_r($files);

?>
```

Both methods output an array with ftp directories/files.

Comment: you can follow the first method, because that method is secure one to connect to FTP and scan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion is that first one is preferable, why:

1. It clearly states that it is ftp connection, which means that you can use it not only for listing files, but for upload too if you need it later, also you can handle errors properly and provide better error messages or logging
2. Second method relies on [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) settings, which is better to disable because of possible security vulnerabilities